# Php Variable in loop is not returning the values I want in html

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I want to echo 4 lines of code. The variable `$x` shall be `1,2,3,4` and the variable `$y` shall be `3,4,5,6`.

The `$x` variable in my loop works fine, the `$y` however doesn't work like I want it (so it echoes `3,4,5,6` later in HTML)

So my question is: Why is the `$y` variable not returning `3,4,5,6` in my final HTML code.

```
for ($x=0; $x<=3;$x++) {
$y=3;
if (${"interferer" .$x} == true) {
  echo "<li><a href='#tabs-$y'>Interferer $x</a></li>";
}
else {
  echo "<!--<li><a href='#tabs-$y'>Interferer $x</a></li>-->";

}
$y++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're setting `$y=3;` every time, it will never increment.

Try moving `$y=3;` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: We all make these mistakes. Glad to help.

Comment: sure, i was waiting for the 10min to pass ;)

Comment: Wow is it 10 mins... I thought it was less than that. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In every iteration you are making `$y=3;` and increasing it at the end

Answer (score 1):

Y variable is getting initialize at the start of loop everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code so that initialize `$y` before you enter the `for` loop

```
$y=3; //Move outside of for loop
for ($x=0; $x<=3;$x++) {
    if (${"interferer" .$x} == true) {
        echo "<li><a href='#tabs-$y'>Interferer $x</a></li>";
    } else {
        echo "<!--<li><a href='#tabs-$y'>Interferer $x</a></li>-->";

    }
    $y++;
}
```

How you had it previously mean that `$y` was getting reset to the value `3` on every iteration of the loop thus destroying the incrementation

Answer (score 0):

it is simply because your $y is reset every loop to three,
you need to take it out of the loop....

```
$y=3;  // here :)
for ($x=0; $x<=3;$x++) {
    //$y=3; //not here!
    if (${"interferer" .$x} == true) {
        echo "<li><a href='#tabs-$y'>Interferer $x</a></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<!--<li><a href='#tabs-$y'>Interferer $x</a></li>-->";
    }
    $y++;
}
```